# Is there a one step operation to select all the records in a QGIS layer?

Tags: qgis

Is there a one step operation to select all the records in a layer or dataset in QGIS? I can't find any reference to a single button, menu command or keyboard shortcut to achieve this.

I am aware of workarounds such as the following:

- Selecting one record in the attribute table, inverting the selection and then reselecting the now unselected record
- Running an advanced select with a static 'True' condition such as 1=1.
- Using a marquee or other polygon select tool over the entire layer extent in the map window

I'm running QGIS 1.7.4 on Windows 7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In current versions of QGIS, you can find the **Select All Features** tool in the toolbar:

[image]

---

Original answer:

**Select all** is available in **SelectPlus menu**. You might have to activate this plugin but it should be shipped with 1.7.0.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, and I see that I can set up a keyboard shortcut to the select all option once the plugin is loaded. It looks as though a lot of the other functions in the **SelectPlus** plugin have already been incorporated into the core code, so I will submit a feature request for Select All as well.

Answer (score 3):

Good question! I've not found a single button, but you can do the attribute table invert method without having to select one record first. At least with version 1.7.0.

I'm sure @underdark will come up with some alternative; but if not, it would be worth putting in a [feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues).

Comment: I hadn't thought of inverting when no records were selected - thanks!

Comment: it would be nice to have this as a feature..probably like right-click of a Layer in Table of Contents -> Select All

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it from the Python QGIS API or create a dedicated button for this, you just need to reuse the [`selectAll()`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a71016ad3897d81831c9336bd01279003) method from class [`QgsVectorLayer`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) (don't know when it appeared).

Considering a vector layer selected in your layer tree, you can try `iface.activeLayer().selectAll()`

Answer (score 2):

[image: This is the select all button, found in the toolbar of the attribute table]

This is the select all button, found in the toolbar of the attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know  whether one step action to select all feature or not but with following option , you can do it if you dont know...

Right Click your features file (Layer) and then select Open Attribute Table you can select all or with Invert Selection button you can select inverse feature too...

and in Advanced Search button you can do advanced selection...